# How to use LGoodDatePicker plugin in Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I am doing an attendance management system using java swing using **Netbeans**, in order to get the `in time` and `out time` i tried to use the java library [LGoodDatePicker](https://github.com/LGoodDatePicker) , I downloaded the files from their official GitHub profile and i don't know how to use it(Get the components in palette Manager and add those to project). And i couldn't find any tutorials or there documentations,
 I know to add a .jar file, but i don't see any here. Can anybody help me how to do ?

Answer (score 2):

You should simply follow [*Managing a Project's Classpath*](https://netbeans.org/kb/74/java/project-setup.html) section within the project setup documentation to add an external ***JAR*** as a library.

Once you have downloaded [the final release of the *LGoodDatePicker* library](https://github.com/LGoodDatePicker/LGoodDatePicker/releases/download/v10.4.1-Standard/LGoodDatePicker-10.4.1.jar), you should follow the aforementioned steps.

Comment: First link is dead